# New data showing with old data in a Spinner

Tags: android

I have two spinners in my app where data in second spinner depends on the selection of first spinner. Data in both the spinners are populating from the server.

The data is fetching successfully but the problem is when I change the selection in first spinner then in second spinner new data loads but old list do not removes it comes along with the new data. I want to show data based on latest selection in first spinner.

Below is my code:

```
Spinner spinState,spinCity,spinPin;

List<String> stateList = new ArrayList<>();
List<String> cityList = new ArrayList<>();

List<AdminFilterStatesModel> adminStateList = new ArrayList<>();
List<AdminFilterCitiesModel> adminCityList = new ArrayList<>();

 stateList.add("Select state");

    ArrayAdapter<String> statespinAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, stateList);

    statespinAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinState.setAdapter(statespinAdapter);

    spinState.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            state = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
            ((TextView) parent.getChildAt(0)).setTextColor(Color.GRAY);

            //showing cities in another spinner based on selection
            if(!(state.equals("Select state"))){

                getCities(state);
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });

    cityList.add("Select city");

     ArrayAdapter<String> cityspinAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, cityList);

    cityspinAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinCity.setAdapter(cityspinAdapter);

    spinCity.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            city = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
            ((TextView) parent.getChildAt(0)).setTextColor(Color.GRAY);

        }
        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });

   //Showing states in first spinner 

   private void getStates(){

    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .connectTimeout(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .readTimeout(20,TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .writeTimeout(20,TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .build();


    Request request = new Request.Builder().url(STATE_URL).build();

    client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(@NotNull Call call, @NotNull final Response response) throws IOException {

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {

                    try {

                        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response.body().string());

                        if(jsonArray.length()>0){

                            for(int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++){

                                JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                                String str1 = jsonObject.getString("state");

                                AdminFilterStatesModel model = new AdminFilterStatesModel(str1);
                                adminStateList.add(model);
                            }

                            for(int i =0;i<adminStateList.size();i++){

                                stateList.add(adminStateList.get(i).getStates());

                            }
                        }

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NotNull Call call, @NotNull final IOException e) {

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),e.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
        }
    });
}

 private void getCities(String state){

    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .connectTimeout(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .readTimeout(20,TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .writeTimeout(20,TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .build();

    RequestBody formBody = new FormBody.Builder()
            .add("state",state)
            .build();

    Request request = new Request.Builder().post(formBody).url(CITY_URL).build();

    client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(@NotNull Call call, @NotNull final Response response) throws IOException {

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {

                    try {

                        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response.body().string());

                        if(jsonArray.length()>0){

                            for(int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++){

                                JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                                String str1 = jsonObject.getString("city");

                                AdminFilterCitiesModel model = new AdminFilterCitiesModel(str1);
                                adminCityList.add(model);
                            }
                            for(int i =0;i<adminCityList.size();i++){

                                cityList.add(adminCityList.get(i).getCity());
                            }
                        }

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NotNull Call call, @NotNull final IOException e) {

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),e.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Add this  line "adminCityList = new ArrayList<>();" in your "getCities()" i think getCities id for second spinner right? So, by adding this line your city list will be empty and new data will filled.

Comment: Because you don't clear Arraylist. Add 'cityList.clear()' section to getCities() method header.

Answer (score 1):

Try below code

```
spinState.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            state = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
            ((TextView) parent.getChildAt(0)).setTextColor(Color.GRAY);

            //showing cities in another spinner based on selection
            if(!(state.equals("Select state"))){

                adminCityList.clear()//add this also
                cityList.clear(); //add this line
                getCities(state);

            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: Its still showing old data with new data when I am selecting some other state in first spinner.

Comment: Its working now but in second spinner selected item is not showing in spinner after get selected.

Comment: you mean when you select city it is not selected..!!

Comment: First item is not selected at first but after selecting another and then come to first its get selected

Comment: cityList.add("Select city"); put this line before this  loop for(int i =0;i<adminCityList.size();i++){

                                cityList.add(adminCityList.get(i).getCity());
                            }

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208568/discussion-between-nice-umang-and-digvijay).